# Pandoc not recognized as R library

Tags: r, pandoc

I installed Pandoc manually through this installation - [link](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

After restarting the system, I was able to locate the installation folder at `C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/Pandoc`

But when I'm trying to call the library:

```
library("pandoc", lib.loc = "C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/Pandoc")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in library("pandoc", lib.loc = "C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/Pandoc") : 
  no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
```

As i'm behind a firewall, I cannot install pandoc through github. So the install.pandoc() function is out.

Any ideas where I'm getting the installation process wrong?

**Edit:**

I've changed .LibPath to point to Pandoc's installation folder:

```
.libPaths('C:/Users/stefanj/AppData/Local/Pandoc')
```

And if I check, it seems to be ok:

```
> grep("pandoc", list.files(.libPaths()))
  [1] 22 24
```

library(pandoc)

```
Error in library(pandoc) : there is no package called ‘pandoc’
Execution halted
```

Comment: have you tried loading the library without specifying the lib path? As an alternative, add it to the `.libPaths` by `.libPaths('C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/', .libPaths)` and try it again.

Comment: @drmariod just did and not working again. I'm getting an error: no package called pandoc.

Comment: @StefanJovanovski : try `grep("pandoc", list.files(.libPaths()))` and if it returns `integer(0)` means package is not installed

Comment: Pandoc isn't an R package. It is a used by some R packages though. What are you trying to do and why do you think you need an R pannage named pandoc

Comment: @Dason I'm running an RScript from cmd that is knitting and rendering data. So I need pandoc for the second part.

Comment: @parth the file is not installed in the standard .libPath folder. Rather, Pandoc gets installed through an .msi as a standalone package in C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/ directory.

Comment: Right. Pandoc isn't an r package though. If you've already installed it manually check to see if it's in your path so that your system knows where to find it.

Comment: I updated the question. But I still cant figure out the problem.

Comment: I'll repeat it again.... Pandoc is not an R package. Changing libpaths tells r where to search for R packages so it won't help you. You need to modify your system path to include pandoc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to @Dason's point that library in path : `"C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/Pandoc"` is not any library/package connected with `R`. It's just `pandoc` installed.

Other way to install `pandoc` would be using [`installr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html) :

```
installr::install.pandoc()
```

Now, for performing for converting from one markup format to another, use the following package :

[`rmarkdown`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html)

The [rmarkdown](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf) package includes high level functions for converting to a variety of formats. For
example:

```
render("input.Rmd", html_document())
render("input.Rmd", pdf_document())
```

Hope this helps.